# Error C2447, C2143, C2059: Basic Visual C++ Class Definition

Tags: c++-cli

I'm just trying to create a class in visual C++ but keep getting the three errors mentioned above:

> Line 9: error C2447: `'{'` : missing function header (old-style formal list?) in UIAutomationCPP.cpp
>   Line 9: error C2143: syntax error : missing `';'` before `'{'` in UIAutomationCPP.cpp
>   Line 9: error C2059: syntax error : `')'` in UIAutomationCPP.cpp

My code for the project is as follows:

```cpp
// File Name: AutomationCPP.h
#pragma once
#ifndef AUTOMATIONCPP_H
#define AUTOMATIONCPP_H

#include "Stdafx.h"

using namespace System;

namespace AutomationCPP
{
    public ref class CustomAutomationCPP
    {
    public:
        CustomAutomationCPP();
        int first;

    private:
        int second;
    };
}
#endif
```

And the class .cpp file:

```cpp
// File Name: AutomationCPP.cpp
#include "Stdafx.h"
#include "AutomationCPP.h"

using namespace System;

AutomationCPP::CustomAutomationCPP()
{
}
```

Please help! I feel if I can get past this, the rest should be much easier.

Comment: Just FYI, including the precompiled header `stdafx.h` into other headers is bad form. Include the precompiled header only into source files.

Answer (score 2):

A constructor is a special member function:

```
AutomationCPP::CustomAutomationCPP::CustomAutomationCPP()
{
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! I never used namespace in C++ before let alone in visual studio. That's an eye opener, thanks a million!

Comment: one note though: Constructors are not functions (ISO 14882:2003, Section 12 _Special member functions_ [special]), but rather "special member functions". I think that's an important point to know for beginners, so as to not learn to misuse constructor-calls.

Comment: @Etienne: Not `special kind of`, just `special member function`. It is an official term :) Personally, I'd just say "You must explicitly qualify member definitions, e.g. like this: "

Comment: @phresnel The standard can be picky sometimes.

Comment: @Etienne: It can indeed. But that pickiness is important sometimes ;)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to Etienne's, which I find personally more readful as it removes some noise from the members:

```
namespace AutomationCPP {

CustomAutomationCPP::CustomAutomationCPP()
{
}

void CustomAutomationCPP::foo()
{
}

// ...

} // namespace AutomationCPP
```

Comment: I see, so then I would define the namespace in the cpp file instead of the header file. Sounds like a good suggestion! :)

Comment: @Chef Pharaoh: You must also put the _declaration_ of your class in that namespace. I.e.: header: `namespace foo { class X{ X(); }; }`, source: `namespace foo { X::X() {} }`